# Linux kernel : Remove input handler from a driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

when I see the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` I see this:

```
I: Bus=0010 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0100
N: Name="aml_keypad"
P: Phys=keypad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/c8100580.rc/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=7fffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=103
```

How can I remove a handler from the driver. (I am compiling the kernel for myself)

For example I want to remove mouse0 from handlers

Comment: What actual functional goal are you trying to accomplish here?   If your goal is to say disable a touchpad, there are accepted ways of doing that.

Comment: I want to still use the device but remove the mouse functionality from it. (it is a must for me in fact if you know my use case) . is it possible? @ChrisStratton

Comment: If you turn off all mouse functionality, you can configure CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove handler it is just enough to comment the related `_set_bit` in the driver source code. In my case :

```
// __set_bit(BTN_MOUSE, dev->input_device->keybit);
// __set_bit(BTN_LEFT, dev->input_device->keybit);
// __set_bit(BTN_RIGHT, dev->input_device->keybit);
// __set_bit(BTN_MIDDLE, dev->input_device->keybit);
//
// __set_bit(EV_REL, dev->input_device->evbit);
// __set_bit(REL_X, dev->input_device->relbit);
// __set_bit(REL_Y, dev->input_device->relbit);
// __set_bit(REL_WHEEL, dev->input_device->relbit);
```

The above snippet is part of this [file](https://github.com/khadas/linux/blob/khadas-vims-nougat/drivers/amlogic/input/remote/remote_core.c).